# Android - add YouTube Data API to project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, youtube

I am trying to include youtube data api in my application, but I cant figure it out how to do it correctly.

Here is the folder of the library that I downloaded:
 
Folder content Image
[image: Folder content Image]

How can I add it to android studio's project?\
I tried to add one of the jar files in the photo, but then the jars in the libs folder, cant be used.

** I want **all** the content of the folder to be applied in android studio.

Comment: try this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Comment: I dont need the Player API, I need the Data APi, because I want to search for videos by keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Please check youtube video search demo app

[https://github.com/Keshava11/LatentLoader](http://Github%20youtube%20video%20search%20demo)